# Custom WebPart Timing out after 5 minutes exactly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 webpart that is timing out after 5 minutes when on the QA servers. The QA environment is 1 web server, 2 app servers, and a SQL server. I've tried EVERYTHING to fix this. Changed the IIS timeouts, worker failures, disabled ping checks and nothing works.  It's the simplest code in the world!!

Could someone please try this on one of your environments? Preferably one with multiple servers making up the farm. This code works perfectly on our dev servers which is just one box. All I am doing is calling the SPLongOperation, sleeping for 6 minutes, and ending the long operation.

Anyone have a clue what I'm missing?

Code:

```
    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

        using (SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))
        {
            operation.LeadingHTML = "Updating Reports on Selected Project Sites";
            operation.TrailingHTML = "Gathering the worker threads, this could take a second. Please stand by...";
            operation.Begin();

            Thread.Sleep(360000);                

            operation.End(currentUrl, SPRedirectFlags.Default, this.Context, "");

        }

        SetStatus("Slept for a long time!", false);
    }
```

Interestingly, if I run the below operation where I don't navigate to the long operation page, it makes me re-authenticate but then redirects me to the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" screen. Very odd.

```
    protected void btnTest2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetStatus("Before Sleep", false);
        Thread.Sleep(360000);
        SetStatus("Sleep Successful!", false);
    }
```